# Once I have the HWND from a Win32 DLL, can I get the coordinates of the native window (even when the window moves )

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Thanks to the experts who monitor this forum, this Java programmer can successfully get the HWND (handle to a native window on the desktop) via JNI.
My goal is to get the window coordinates ( x, y ) of this native window to work on a screen-share project. In the calling java program, I will need the "coordindates" even if the window is moved by the user ( the coordinates change ...).

My question to you is, will this handle give me the dynamic values of the coordindates ( that changed when the window was moved), or will I need to keep calling the native dll to see if the values changed ?
I am hoping that I can just call the native procedure "once" and the window handle can give me the dynamic values. If I have to keep calling the native procedure, then I might as well pass the coordinates ( Point from GetRect..()) rather than the HWND ?

Comment: No, you must call WinAPI every time to see if the coordinates changed. And HWND is the mandatory parameter for WinAPI calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could try GetWindowLong() (with GWL_WNDPROC (-4)) from within your JNI DLL, which will allow you to re-direct the other WndProc() address to your app, and intercept every message sent to the window and then monitor the important changes.  I have done this in Win32 native C++ apps, but never in Java.  It may work though.

```
oldAddress = GetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC );
SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, myWndProc );
```

And from within your WndProc(), use:

```
CallWindowProc( oldAddress, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam );
```

You can check IsValidWindow( hwnd ) to make sure the window is still in scope.  When your program exits, make sure you call:

```
SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, oldAddress );
```

Comment: Almost lost hope on that question, so thank you, let me try it ! @RickHodgin

Answer (score 0):

I believe the windows API GetWindowRect() does exactly this